# how to call a method with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method `sendMail(list)`. This method will send the mails to the recipients which are there in the list.

```
public void sendMail(List<DTO> dto) {


        for(DTO individualObject: dto) {
            
            bulkMailSender.sendSimpleMessage(individualObject.getEmail(),masterDetails.getMailSubject() , content, masterDetails.getMailFrom(), individualObject); 
            try {
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(Long.parseLong(individualObject.getTimegap().trim()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

I have this kind of method. I want to run this method Thread based, when one thread is executing the mails, I should allow the other thread to access `sendMail` and send simultaneously together. Each and every `individualObject` contains it's own sleep time.

How can I make it worked with the multiple threads.

Let's take an example

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SleepClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SleepClass s= new SleepClass();
        s.m1(10000);
        s.m1(20000);
        
        
    }
    
    public void m1(int time) {
        
        for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

In the above example I have a regular method and it is executing one by one. How can make it simultaneous execution

Comment: Note that `if(!dto.isEmpty())` is unnecessary, because the enhanced `for` loop here already implies that.

Comment: Regarding your question – what exactly is the issue you are facing? Is there something not working? Do you encounter exceptions thrown?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Just call `sendMail` from different threads and it will be executed in parallel.

Comment: @Henry Ok my issue is if we know how many threads are going to access my application then I can call directly with `Thread t1 = new Thread(new MagicTask());` t1.start();. If we dont know how to call that method with different threads?

Comment: every application that wants to access this method will create a new thread. So you don't have to instantiate threads upfront. If you want to limit the number of parallel threads you need to setup a queue and a threadpool.

Comment: @Conffusion you mean if two requests comes to my method then it will execute both simultaneously?

Comment: yes, and the success of it will depend also on how thread safe `bulkMailSender` is because it is instantiated outside your method so can potentially be shared by .multiple threads.

Comment: @Conffusion I have updated the example in my question. Please look into that that is executing one by one not simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need simultaneous execution and each time new thread you can find the solution here

```
public class SleepClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SleepClass s= new SleepClass();
        s.m2(500);
        s.m2(1000);
    }
    
    public void m2(int time) {
        SleepClass s= new SleepClass();
        new Thread(() -> {
            s.m1(time);
        }).start();
    }
    
    public void m1(int time) {
        
        for(int i = 0; i<= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your logic in a Runnable and launch it using new `Thread(runnable).start()`.
To pass parameters to each runnable define them as class variables so you can pass them via the constructor and use them in the `run` method:

```
public class SleepClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SleepClass s= new SleepClass();
        s.m1(10000);
        s.m1(20000);
    }
    
    public void m1(int time) {
        for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
            new Thread(new Launcher(i,time)).start();
        }
    }

    public class Launcher implements Runnable {
        int i;
        int time;
        public Launcher(int i, int time) {
            this.i=i;
            this.time=time;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This program also printing the same `01230123` is the output, means it is not executing simultaneously

Comment: That is not possible as it will only print from 0 to 2. My output was: 0,2,1,1,0,2. And the second time: 0,2,1,0,1,2